# How would i have a class return a list, tuple or dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, class

I want to have a class return a list, tuple or dictionary
and use it like a regular list.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for i in range(len(args)):
            args[i] += 1
  
    def __some_dunder_method__(self):
        return self.args

obj = MyClass(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4)

print(obj[1])    # Wanted output: 2
print(obj[2:5])  # Wanted output: [3, 4, 5]
print("Yes" if 3 in obj else "No")  # Wanted output: Yes
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Don't do that.  Consistency is key to good programming,  Pick one (list or tuple) and have it behave that way.  What you have above will work with either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this with the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods.  This code just forwards those routines straight to the embedded list (which you forgot to create):

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.args = []
    for i in range(len(args)):
      self.args.append( args[i] + 1 )
  
  def __getitem__(self,n):
    return self.args.__getitem__(n)
  
  def __setitem__(self,n,k):
    return self.args.__setitem__(n,k)

obj = MyClass(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4)
print(obj[1]) # Wanted Output: 2
print(obj[2:5]) # Wanted Output: [3, 4, 5]

if 3 in obj: print("Yes")
else: print("No")
# Wanted Output: Yes
```

Output:

```
2
[3, 4, 5]
Yes
```

Alternatively, you can get the same effect just by deriving from the list type:

```
class MyClass(list):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    for i in range(len(args)):
      self.append( args[i] + 1 )
```

Same output.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you can inherit from the appropriate built-in class (e.g., list) and customize your class accordingly. Here's an example using the list class:

```
class MyClass(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
         super().__init__([i + 1 for i in args])

    def __contains__(self, item):
         return super().__contains__(item - 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = MyClass(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4)

    # Accessing elements
    print(obj[1])  # Wanted Output: 2
    print(obj[2:5])  # Wanted Output: [3, 4, 5]

    # Checking if an element is in the object
    if 3 in obj:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")  # Wanted Output: Yes
```